# personalizando el comportamiento del flex para responsive cards bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, flexbox, grid

La imagen 1 es mi diseño actual cuando el tamaño de la pantalla es grande , **(quiero que esta parte se mantenga asi)** y hacer que que cuando la pantalla sea de un tamaño mas pequeño en vez de un comportamiento de columna(uno sobre otro)sea de row (**2 sea como la imagen 2 uno al lado de otro**)que el comportamiento para pantallas mas pequennas sea de la forma de la imagen de abajo... o que el contenido se ponga debajo de mi `<main></main>` o que se esconda como un **sidebar** igual me pudiera ser util.

[image: imagen 1]

para pantalla grande se mantenga asi..

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/spacelab/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Container Principal -->
<div class="container-fluid my-5"> 
 <div class="row"> 
  <!-- Sidebar -->
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
  <div class="card my-4">
   <div class="card-header"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>User</div>
   <div class="card-body">
     <h4 class="card-title">Links</h4>
     <p class="card-text">Some quick example</p>
   </div><!-- card body-->
    </div><!-- card -->
    
    <div class="card my-4">
   <div class="card-header">Otros</div>
   <div class="card-body">
     <p class="card-text">text</p>
   </div>
    </div><!-- card -->
 </div>
 
 <main role="main" class="ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pr-4"></main>
  </div>
  </div>
```

[image: imagen r]

para pantalla sea pequeña quede asi...

Comment: Has intentado algo? Estás preguntando varias cosas en una sola publicació, por favor trata de ser más claro para que podamos brindarte una posible solución.

Comment: si esta imagen que vez arriba la numero 3 la hice cambiando varias cosas y  agregando  `d-flex flex-row` a la clase que la contiene pero me distorsiona el diseño para pantalla grande.. cree un nuevo `div row` pero me igual me distorsiona.. poniendo clases flex a los card tampoco funciona..

Comment: Puedes subir el código HTML de tu `<main>`? Ya revisaste trabajar con los _breakpoints_ de Bootstrap para cada una de las vistas?

Comment: puedo subirlo pero todo el problema se encuentra en esa columna donde estan las cards

Comment: no se nada de los breakpoints de bootstrap @JheymanMejia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te propongo esto, ya que usas Bootstrap en su versión 4 usemos únicamente las clases de su [sistema de cuadrícula](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) (*grid system*).

Como bien sabemos, Bootstrap divide la pantalla del dispositivo hasta en 12 columnas. En tu *layout* estás usando dos columnas principales:

> La columna del *`sidebar`* (ocupando 2/12) y la columna en la que
>   tienes tu *`main`* (ocupando 10/12).

Esto para dispositivos con un ancho superior a `992px` en su pantalla.

[image: layout para escritorio]

A partir de allí empezamos a jugar con los *puntos de quiebre responsivos* o **[Responsive Breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)**, basándonos en su cuadrícula de columnas, usando las siguientes clases:

```
.col-lg-2 y .col-lg-10 (desde 1200px)
.col-md-3 y .col-md-9 (desde 768px)
.col-sm-12 y .col-sm-12 (desde 576px)
```

Anotación: La última clase la uso para que ocupe todo el ancho del dispositivo y por ende "arrastre" los elementos restantes creando una nueva fila. Aunque no es la opción más bonita, [es totalmente válida](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#column-wrapping).

---

## Al meollo...

Una vez entendido esto, podemos decir que la primer columna, el *`sidebar`*, puede incluir o anidar dentro de sí misma más columnas, es por ello que la dividí en dos dos columnas internas, a las cuales se les puede aplicar las mismas reglas de los puntos de quiebre.

Este sería el *`layout`* simplificado (Ejecuta a pantalla completa y revisa los puntos de quiebre reduciendo la ventana).

```css
.bordes{ 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid;
}

main > .bordes{
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/spacelab/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<!-- CONTENEDOR -->
<div class="container-fluid my-5">

  <!-- ROW PRINCIPAL -->
  <div class="row">    

    <!-- COLUMNA 1 EXTERNA -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">

      <!-- row interno -->
      <div class="row">        

        <!-- col1 interna -->
        <div class=" col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">          
          <div class="bordes">CARD</div>
        </div>

         <!-- col2 interna -->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">         
          <div class="bordes">CARD</div>
        </div>       

      </div>     

    </div>

    <!-- COLUMNA 2 EXTERNA -->
    <main role="main" class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
      <div class="bordes">MAIN</div>
    </main>

  </div>
</div>
```

Así quedaría entonces tu código:

```css
main {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<!-- Container Principal -->
<div class="container-fluid my-5">

  <div class="row">
    <!-- row principal -->

    <!-- Columna 1 externa -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">

      <div class="row">
        <!-- row interno -->
        <!-- col1 interna -->
        <div class=" col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="card my-4">
            <div class="card-header"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>User</div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Links</h4>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example</p>
            </div>
            <!-- card body-->
          </div>
          <!-- card -->
        </div>
        <!-- col1 -->

        <!-- col2 interna -->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="card my-4">
            <div class="card-header">Otros</div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- card -->
        </div>
        <!-- col2 -->
      </div>
      <!-- row interno -->

    </div>

    <!-- columna 2 externa -->
    <main role="main" class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-10">
      Contenido Main
    </main>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bien completa la respuesta, gracias colega!

Comment: Muchas gracias y muy buena respuesta Jheyman Mejia... muy util

Comment: ahora tengo mas claro como funciona el sistema de gillas...

Comment: Me alegra que les haya servido! Un saludo!